# Oscillator circuit based on a SAW delay line

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator

I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction for a oscillator circuit that depends on a SAW delay line for control of the frequency.

The SAW central frequency is 20 MHz, for information, and it seems some characterisation of these devices are better performed in frequency, and I've read about oscillator circuits used for these purposes. 
I would like to get an idea of the setup necessary and happening within it.

Any help, advice or pointing to resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any specs in mind? https://www.idt.com/document/whp/voltagecontrolledsawosc-vcso-fundamentals

Comment: If the SAW delay is longer than 1 cycle at 20MHz, then a single-port negative-resistance oscillator may be your only choice.

Comment: Thank you for link @TonyEErocketscientist I do not have a particular spec in mind. I am kind of figuring this out as I go along. I am fabricating the SAW devices configured as a sensor, with SAW velocity affected by measurands. But there is difficulty measuring the delay and frequency measurement approach was suggested and I have seen oscillators circuits have been used. I am looking for a relatively simple starting point that I can play about with to improving my understanding and refine in time.

Comment: If you read my recent answer on group delay , you will see the delay of a burst sine is group delay plus phase shift.  Thus there can be many cycles of phase shift in the pass band hence why the VCSO has many control points.